# nomencl latex won't show output

Tags: indexing, latex

```
\documentclass[9pt,conference,a4paper,twocolumn]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature


\begin{document}


\nomenclature{$k$}{set of hourly intervals}
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

I am trying to run this nomenclature code using TexStudio. I get error everytime, even if I already specified the makeindex as what I read from other reviews. 
  Here is what I specified:
***makeindex (arb).nlo -s nomencl.ist -o (arb).nls***

*NOTE: where arb is the filename of my tex.*

Everytime I ran the code, there are no errors. However, when I check via ***TOOLS/INDEX*** ,the errors are:

```
Process started: makeindex (arb).nlo -s nomencl.ist -o (arb).nls
Input index file (arb).nlo not found. Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] 
[-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]

Process exited with error(s)
```

THANKS hopefully for the help

Comment: Dear reviewers, this is a pure tex problem and unrelated to programming. I think it would be best if it would be migrated to tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The `titlesec` package does not work in combination with the `IEEEtran` document class. During compilation it causes the error `Undefined control sequence. \ttl@extract\subparagraph`. Without an successfully tex run first, makeindex will not have the necessary information to create the index.

Once this problem is fixed, the nomenclatur can be generated with

```
makeindex ⟨filename⟩.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o ⟨filename⟩.nls
```

---

```
\documentclass[9pt,conference,a4paper,twocolumn]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature


\begin{document}

test

\nomenclature{$k$}{set of hourly intervals}
\nomenclature{$d$}{set of daily intervals}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @samcarter! But I have somehow let it work with the package titlesec. However, can you help me put the nomenclature title on left aligned and with boldface? Thanks

Comment: @Kirii Very interesting that titlesec works for you. With an up-to-date texlive2019 I get an error for `\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}`

Comment: @Kirii Please ask a new question for the bold and left aligned title

Comment: I have found a mistake, I cannot add further nomenclatures. And if I change the data, it will repeatedly output the 1st specified nomenclature. @samcarter

Comment: @Kirii I cannot reproduce this, multiple nomenclatures work fine for me. Is your tex distribution up-to-date? (the fact that titlesec does not cause an error for you makes me think something strange is going on with your distribution ....)

Comment: How would I know if my tex-distribution is up-to-date? And how would I update if not? @samcarter  I removed title sec, the same results show

Comment: @Kirii To check if your distribution is up to date, add `\listfiles` to your preamble. After compiling, you can find a list of packages and their version information in the `.log` file. Please add this information to your question.

Comment: I just found out, that whenever I put lines of nomenclature, it will print for one time only and can't be edit. I copy and past my files into a new tex file to try this , to prove if it's just a bug or I don't know what it is. @samcarter

Comment: @Kirii Can you add your complete log file to the question? (not as an additional answer)

Comment: Thanks for the response @samcarter! I have troubleshoot the problem. It needs to be test via Tools-index-then run if you want to add another line of nomenclature.

Answer (score 0):

```
makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls -t %.nlg
```

I have somehow solve this problem after various tries, I change the index which is above and it ran smoothly without errors in TeXStudio even if titlesec package is use. 
NOTE: To add ***multiple nomenclatures***, every time you encode the nomenclature, ***test index  via Tools then RUN***. it will solve the mentioned problems.